# Any idea why adonis migration command not working?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, adonis.js

[Adonis command neither give error nor works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maNSQ.png)

I just clone the `Node project` from one PC to another. Installed `npm` and adonis. Now my Node project is working when I open the URL at which it is serving it shows me the login page. 
When in try to execute the Migration command, cli is neither executing the command nor giving any error.

Comment: If you run this command: `adonis -h` what's the result?

Comment: Thanks for your response. this is the result for "adonis -h"
Usage: index [options] [command]

Options:
  -V, --version         output the version number
  -h, --help            output usage information

Commands:
  new [options] <name>  Scaffold a new AdonisJs application with the name provid
ed.
  Extras:

    [command] --help output command detail info

Comment: The problem is only with `adonis migration:...` commands? `adonis serve --dev` works?

Comment: `adonis serve --dev` is also not working, i run project by npm start..

Comment: Try to reinstall `@adonisjs/cli` with `npm uninstall -g @adonisjs/cli` and `npm i -g @adonisjs/cli`. Now the command `adonis serve --dev` is working?

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall `@adonisjs/cli` :

*Uninstall (Globally):*

```sh
> npm uninstall -g @adonisjs/cli
```

*Install (Globally):*

```sh
> npm i -g @adonisjs/cli
```

*`@adonisjs/cli` must be installed [globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally) (it's not a project dependency)*

[Installation - AdonisJS documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/installation)